# How do I parse and search xml for a specific node value then have access to other child nodes?

Tags: jquery

Im using the following code to search a local xml source and Im trying to...

1.) search / filter for the player xml node where the findplayername variable matches the playername attribute OR the name node in the XML  (I can change the xml source nodes / attributes however I want if that helps)

2.) then be able to write out / access the node values for the other nodes such as id and twid that correspond to the findplayername match -- if that makes any sense.

Im not sure how the loop and function should loo, but heres what I've tried... can anyone shed any light on this for me?

```
function getTwitterID(findplayername){
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "myxmlfile.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {

            $(data.player).each(function (i, item) {

        $(xml).find("name").text() == findplayername;
        });
           }
});
 };
```

My returned XML looks like this:

```
<players>
    <player playername="Jim Smith">
      <id>1</id>
      <name>Jim Smith</name>
      <twid>abc</twitterid>
    </player>
    <player playername="Jane Doe">
      <id>2</id>
      <name>Jane Doe</name>
      <twid>xyz</twitterid>
    </player>
</players>
```

EDIT -- this worked  perfectly thanks @Ohgodwhy:

```
function getTwitterID(findplayername){
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "myxmlfile.xml"",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {

        $(xml).find('player').each(function(i, item){
            if($(this).find('name').text() == findplayername){
                console.log($(this).find('twid').text());
            }
        });
    }
});
```

};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's just a bad copy-pasta or if you've legitimately declared your variables wrong, but it should be :

```
$(xml).find('player').each(function(){
    $(xml).find('name').text(findplayername);
});
```

Observe the above,y ou also can't use jQuery as a getter and a setter but rather need to pass your value to the function as an argument so it can be evaluated. Unless I'm wrong about the above and meant to do a comparison of course:

```
$(xml).find('player').each(function(){
    if($(this).find('name').text() == findplayername)){
        //do something
    }
});
```

Comment: answer accepted - used you 2nd method and tweaked it a bit and edited answer to show how I adapted it.  Many thanks.